# Laravel api - 405 not allowed shared hosting

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and i have the next problem.

I have an API POST route that works properly in the localhost. I send POST requests from POSTMAN:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api_import'], function () {
    Route::get('/products', [ArticlesController::class, 'index']);

    Route::post('/products', [ArticlesController::class, 'addOrUpdateArticles']);
    Route::post('/categories', [CategoriesController::class, 'addOrUpdateCategories']);
});
```

However, it will not work on hosting. Hosting is shared, and I get the message:

[image]

When json contains a couple of products everything works properly. When json contains a complete table of 3500 products I get this error.

Comment: What hosting provider are you using? Check the network inspector for something like a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, which'll break your POST.

Comment: There is also one middleware, but it doesn't write anything in the log file when I send the whole JSON.

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {   
        \Log::info("headers");
        \Log::info($request->headers); 
        return $next($request); 
    }

Comment: Are you able to share a URL to the endpoint for us to take a look?

Comment: When I go to that first URL I get a 404 page.

Comment: When it opens from the browser, you get 404 pages.

But it's an api route and I send requests from the postman.

I also set up a json that you can try from the postman

Comment: `curl -X POST https://nbk.rs/api/proizvodi` gives me a 404, too, and your routes file shows a route called `products`. I'm pretty confused here about your actual setup.

Comment: Then I strongly suspect you're making your POST call to `http://nbk.rs/api/products` when you should be doing it to `https://nbk.rs/api/products`, and that the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is what's causing the 405.

Comment: I just did. POSTing works fine. I get `Trying to get property 'acClassif' of non-object (View: /home/nbkrs/nbkfiles/resources/views/components/frontend/partials/arrivals.blade.php)`, though.

Comment: Yes, there is that page on the site, but I don't know what it has to do with the API. Api is simple and I don’t get that mistake, I don’t know why.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would ask you to delete the domain name from your comments because after all this is a "live" server in production so there is no need to see it anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a redirect on the page. You should confirm this through the network tab in your browser, because any `POST` request with a redirect is considered a `GET` request, so an error appears (405 Method Not Allowd)

Comment: How can I see from the network tab when I send requests from POSTMAN to a remote server?

Comment: In your browser right click on the page and chose `inspect` then open `network` tab and chose `XHR` or `ALL` then reload your page. after this any request will display for you